# Permission Error Buildozer.Permission error no 13

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I am new to kivy and also in python. I was just creating my first app into apk. But I get very much errors.after many research on internet,I got solution but of this error. I am not able to solve and also not getting solution. (My English is weak. So, try to understand.And I am doing in colab in Google browser in phone)

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2080, in __init__ os.execve(cmd[0], cmd, ca["env"]) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/content/drive/MyDrive/Monster/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/monster_new_card/gradlew'
```

For this error I also run this command

```
!chmod +x /content/drive/MyDrive/Monster/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/monster_new_card/gradlew
```

Command got successful.

To give access but it not solve. Why I don't know? Now,what can I do to solve it,can anyone help me?

```
         Thanks for solution
```